# Make link from an url from data Vue

Tags: html, vue.js

In my data below, i have some url but I don't want it to be present as a text. How can I present it as a link?

I tried to use some regex but it just doesn't work. Yeah it can change the text, but it can't change the url to the link

```
<pre style="white-space: pre-line;font-family: inherit;">
  {{ page.body }}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I did catch what you meant to say, you want to print a url underlined just like the `<a>` tag does? then you should use that `<a>` tag!

Like this:

```html
<a :href="url">{{url}}</a>
```

```
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            url: "https://media.giphy.com/media/13VFATn4bxBCXm/giphy.gif",
        }
    }
}
```

Using `:` before the attribute `href` to bind it

Comment: Sorry for not clear about my question, page.body contains a lot of text. And in that text, it has some url and I want to make that url to become link. Any suggestion?

Comment: Okay so you have a long block of text and in inside it are a couple urls that you want to print like, once again, the tag <a> does? the only thing I can come up is: You have to format you text using html like:
<p>Some text</p><br>
<h2>Header</h2><br>
<a href="url">Some url</a>
And then bind the html att of your wrapper <pre :v-html="myFormattedText"> </pre> it will inject the code in it as if it were actual html code, I hope it helps you